# Donation by inductive effect and withdrawal by conjugation

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Is there a group that would attached to a benzene ring, donate electrons by inductive effect and withdraw them by conjugation?

Comment: Well, I guess a $\ce{-BH2}$ group attached to benzene ring would have this effect. It has an empty $\ce{p}$ orbital that would withdraw electrons via conjugation, but $\ce{B}$ is less electronegative than $\ce{C}$ and so it would have a positive inductive effect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now, an additional question: Where would substitution happen on the aromatic ring?

Comment: Usually conjugation beats inductive effects. So substitution should happen in the *meta* position.

Comment: How probable is ipso substitution?

Comment: @Marko It's okay to ask a new question for follow-ups.  If you want to reference that it's a continuation of this question, you can link to this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess a $\ce{-BH2}$ group attached to a benzene ring would have this effect. It has an empty $\ce{p}$ orbital that would withdraw electrons via conjugation, but $\ce{B}$ is less electronegative than $\ce{C}$ and so it would have a positive inductive effect.